# Understanding mutable Seq

Tags: scala, collections

I'm pretty new to Scala and try to understand mutable `Seq`. Since it's in package `mutable` I expected there is a method that allows us to append element without copying the whole collection.

But there is no `+=` method in the `mutable.Seq`, but in `Buffer` is. `:+` and `+:` both copy the collection.

So why is it mutable?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Because `mutable` and `growable` isn't the same thing. 
(the latter is one specific type of the former: everything, that's growable is mutable, but not everything that's mutable is growable).

`mutable.Seq` has `update`, that allows you to change the element at a given index, but it does not grow or shrink. 
`Buffer` is s specialization of `Seq`, that is both mutable and growable.

Answer (score 4):

As explained in the [documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/mutable/Seq.html), `mutable.Seq` adds an update method to `collection.Seq`. `+=` on the other hand is defined in [Growable](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/generic/Growable.html).

In Scala standard library, most mutable collections extend the immutable version, which is why they inherit copying `:+`, `+:`.

Comment: "In Scala standard library, most mutable collections extend the immutable version, which is why they inherit copying `:+`, `+:`." No, they don't. Both mutable and immutable versions (e.g. `collection.mutable.Seq` and `collection.immutable.Seq`) extend a common version (in this case, `collection.Seq`) instead, and that contains `:+` and `+:`. But `collection.mutable.Seq` doesn't extend `collection.immutable.Seq`.

Comment: Indeed, but that that's playing with words. All the methods from `collection.Seq` have "immutable collection" signature, see http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Seq.html#filter(p:A=>Boolean):Repr & co.