# What is the difference between "growable" and "mutable" in a Rust string?

Tags: string, rust, mutable, growable

I'm reading [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html). The [docs define a `String`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html) as "growable":

> A UTF-8 encoded, growable string.

I've [found that growable is not the same as mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415432/understanding-mutable-seq), but
 they don't really explain what makes a type "growable".

Given this `let mut guess = String::new()`,

1. What does "growable" mean?
2. How does `mut` change a growable string?
3. Is there a non-growable string type?

Comment: This reminds me of [another recent question on `str` and their size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54673145/1233251).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overthinking the wording here; "growable" only means that it can grow. A `String` that originally allocated 3 bytes to contain `"abc"` can *grow* to 6 bytes to contain `"abcdef"`. The memory allocation can become bigger (and smaller). There's no specific Rust typesystem meaning to the word "growable".

Changing the capacity of a `String` is a specific type of alteration, so you need a mutable `String` in order to grow the string. You also need a mutable `String` for other types of alterations that don't involve changing the allocation.

A mutable string slice (`&mut str`) is a type of string that cannot become longer or shorter but may be changed.

```
fn example(name: &mut str) {
    name.make_ascii_uppercase()
}
```

See also:

- [What are the differences between Rust's `String` and `str`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24158114/what-are-the-differences-between-rusts-string-and-str)
- [Why can fixed-size arrays be on the stack, but str cannot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54673145/1233251)